# Unable to Parse the data from JSON response in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I just trying to create the country list. I have used the [restcountries API](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/united) to get the country. I am unable to parse the JSON response. Since, the response contains with special characters. So, I have used the [JSONEncoder](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/json.html) and my code is below:

```
import requests
import sys
import ast
import json

url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/united'
r = requests.get(url)
a = r.json()
```

I need result like this `a[0]`. If I printing a directly, getting error as below

[image]

```
b = json.JSONEncoder().encode(a)
print(b)
```

this `print(b)` is working fine. But, unable get the `b[0]`. I am new to python. Please help me If anything wrong and sorry for my poor communication.

Comment: What are you doing here? Why are you getting the decoded JSON and then re-encoding it? It makes no sense.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the decoded JSON throws error as UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xce' in position 28
4: character maps to <undefined>. 

For this I re-encoding again

Comment: *What* gives you that error? Show exactly what you did and the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Instead of printing b, just print a. It will throws the error as above

Comment: Why are you printing it though? You said you just needed to get the name of the first result.

Comment: I just updated the question. Please help me on this case

Comment: Well that update definitely shows that you sent us on a wild goose chase with b = json.JSONEncoder().encode(a)

Comment: can you please reedit your question. The code snippet is now broken into two by your image. Please update your code to reflect my answer.

Comment: You **still** haven't explained why you're printing the whole of `a` when you just want to get `a[0].name`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sometimes I need to check the key names of the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does this do?

```
json.JSONEncoder().encode(a)
```

> Return a JSON string representation of a Python data structure

But what do you have in `a`? json. What are you trying to access an element of a dictionary that is part of the json array

all you need is

```
r = requests.get(url)
a = r.json()
print(a[0]['name'])
```

Comment: But unable to print the a. It shows - UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xce' in position 28 4: character maps to <undefined>.

Comment: @Nisar problem can be with native characters which your terminal/console may not understand so better try `print(a[0]['name'].encode('some_encoding'))` where `some_encoding` can be `utf-8` or other - it depens on your system.

Comment: @e4c5 this code is OK - it works for me on Linux because my console use `utf-8` but some consoles on Windows use `cp437` or other encoding which doesn't display native characters - so OP may have problem with its console and with `print(a)`.

Comment: My system is windows and it has cp437

Comment: then update the question by posting your stacktrace. the obvious conclusion to be drawn from your question is that the encoder call is what causes the problem

Comment: @Nisur see [Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Comment: please delete that comment and post the full stacktrace as part of your question.

Comment: I just updated the question, Please help me on this case.

Comment: With this update the link @furas posted does look like the right option